# Get the time of Main Activity creation

Tags: android

My test activity is declared as the main activity in the manifest. Is there a way I can know the "com.test.testActivity" creation time?

I am not looking for the Activity lifecycle onCreate() but rather the object creation time.

```
I/ActivityManager(  743): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.test.android/com.test.testActivity (has extras)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a long variable you set when the constructor is called.

**P.S. make sure you leave the constructor empty!**

```
public MainActivity() {
    creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

private long creationTime;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("main", "Creation time: " + creationTime);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I think you had the right idea but looks like the Acitivity was not instantiated when the launcher icon is clicked, maybe its just a classpath reference.

Comment: One you launch the app, it will launch the activity associated with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` intent. Are you doing this in the correct class? Also it might take some time for the android to actually instantiate it

Comment: yes, I am doing it in the correct class. Do you know how I can get the launcher icon click time?

Comment: @Sid No, I don't think you can.